# google closure compiler + ant auto link source map auto to source

Tags: javascript, ant, google-closure-compiler

I'am using google closure compiler + ant to pack my project source code and everything works fine with the follow settings (build.xml):

```
<jscomp 
    compilationLevel="advanced" 
    warning="quiet"
    debug="false" 
    output="./game.min.js"
    languagein="ECMASCRIPT5"
    forceRecompile="true"
    sourceMapFormat="V3"
    sourceMapOutputFile="./game.js.map"
>
```

The source code and source map is generated, and by adding a line at hte bottom of the game.min.js code :

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=./game.js.map
```

I am able to see the packed source code linked to unpacked source code successfully.

But my only question here is, every time I recompile the code with ant I will have to add the line above to the generated game.min.js which is pretty inconvenient. Is there a way to get this done automatically by adding some options to the build.xml?

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[via the Closure Compiler FAQ](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#when-using-advanced-optimizations-closure-compiler-adds-new-variables-to-the-global-scope-how-do-i-make-sure-my-variables-dont-collide-with-other-scripts-on-the-page)

You can specify an output wrapper, typically it would be used like this:

```
--output_wrapper "(function() {%output%}).call(window);"
```

But I imagine you could use

```
--output_wrapper "(function() {%output%}).call(window);//@ sourceMappingURL=./game.js.map"
```

or maybe

```
--output_wrapper "(function() {%output%}).call(window);\n//@ sourceMappingURL=./game.js.map"
```